# Twig dump isn't printing anything

Tags: symfony, twig, twig-extension, symfony-2.6

I am a little bit confused right now. I always used the twig dump function like any other twig function but now it has absolutely no output. No errors/exceptions, just nothing.
Everything else is working fine, like the trans filter.

```
{{ dump('test') }} # prints nothing
{{ 'layout.booking.chooseArea'|trans }} # prints the translated message
```

Right now this template doesn't contain anything more than that.
The dump also doesn't work in the parent template or in base.html.twig.

Again, the dump prints nothing: not an empty string, not null, not a single pixel on the screen.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Symfony version: 2.6.x-dev

**update**

```
{{ dump('test') }} # doesn't work (anymore?)
{% dump('test') %} # does (still) work
```

Has this been removed or something? Why are there no errors? By the way... debug flag is set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Symfony 2.6, there is a new VarDumper component and DebugBundle. These override twig's `dump()` function to give a lot more and nicer dump output.

However, you have to register the DebugBundle in your `AppKernel`, otherwise it'll just ignore the call. To do this, you should add this to `app/AppKernel.php`:

```
// app/AppKernel.php

// ...
public function registerBundles()
{
    // ...

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        // ...
    }

    return $bundles;
}
```

Please note that this new dump function will dump the output in the web dev toolbar, to avoid screwing up the page layout.

> In 2.6.0, this will be fixed by having a fallback to the native twig `dump()` function why the DebugBundle is not registered.

Comment: Thank you, interesting information. But I don't see it in the debug toolbar but still in the content. Is there a special configuration value for this?

Comment: Ok I don't know what I did (actually nothing) but now it suddenly appears in the toolbar... and I already love it! :)