# Laravel TwigBridge dump() show nothing

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, twig, lamp

I have a Laravel project and I used Twig instead of Blade as template engine, but suddenly the dump() function is not working anymore.

If i try

```
dump(user)
```

Nothing happen

- no null
- no errror,

Just nothing displayed.

I used TwigBrige 0.7 and Laravel 5.

For a few days I had change my OS to Ubuntu 14.04 and after this the dump() function is not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915293/twig-dump-isnt-printing-anything and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913859/twigs-dump-function-returns-a-blank-screen

Comment: It's dont solve my problem.

Comment: Okay then I guess you need to provide more information, does dump("abc") work? Are there any errors in the laravel.log? is debug enabled?

Comment: It's did'nt work.
The error logs are empty and in my .env file the debugging is setting on true.

Comment: I install my app under a Windows system and dump is working.
Only under Ubuntu it dosen't work :(